# Regexp, How to get string between double slash?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

How to get the whole line up to the second double slash (//)

Example text: "C#//text with any symbols */\ even digits 97878//Other don't need text".

I would get "C#//text with any symbols */\ even digits 97878"

I tried to user `^[^\/]*\/\/[^\/]*` but any slash spoils everything.

Thanks!

Comment: If your regex supports lookaheads then perhaps `^.*?//.*?(?=//)`? https://regex101.com/r/oOCSE5/3

Comment: @Nick Fixed: `/^.*?\/\/.*?(?=\/\/)/` (taking into accound that in the question they are backslshed).

Comment: @extempl definitely if they're using a language that requires `/` delimiters around the regex.

Comment: @Nick btw, what are `.*?` construction for? `?` seem to be redundant.

Comment: @extempl `?` makes `.*` lazy without it the first `.*` will match to the second to last `//` if there is a third (or fourth or ...) `//` in the string (try removing the `?` in my demo link and you'll see what I mean)

Comment: if you always have the second //, you can just do `\/\/(.*)\/\/`, then the content of the capturing group will be your desired text

Comment: @Nick sorry guys, I have to use regex in sql oracle. Oracle doesn't support lookaheads

Comment: @AlexeiDelezhov I've updated your question tags. Please make them as specific as possible when you ask a question about regex, as there are many different flavours...

Comment: @Pavel Lint 
this does not work because i need to get the line before the second // and you regexp cuts the first line and shows the remaining line

Comment: @Nick 
thanks, I’ll fix it now

Comment: @AlexeiDelezhov ah I see. Well if you want the part before the // also, you can use `^(.*\/\/.*)\/\/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said:

> How to get the whole line up to the second double slash (//)

If that's so, you don't need regular expressions; `substr + instr` combination is capable of doing it:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'C#//text with any symbols */\ even digits 97878//Other don''t need text' from dual)
  3  select substr(col, 1, instr(col, '//', 1, 2) - 1) result
  4  from test;

RESULT
-----------------------------------------------
C#//text with any symbols */\ even digits 97878

SQL>
```

`instr(col, '//', 1, 2)` says:

- search string (`col` in this example) for double slash `//`
- starting from the `1`st position in a string
- and find its `2`nd appearance

Answer (score 1):

@Littlefoot answer using `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` is the simple (and best) solution, but if you *want* to use regex you could use [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions163.htm#SQLRF06302) to remove everything after and including the second `//`:

```
with test (col) as
    (select 'C#//text with any symbols */\ even digits 97878//Other don''t // need text' from dual)
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '^(.*?//.*?)//.*$', '\1') result
FROM test
```

Output:

```
RESULT
C#//text with any symbols */\ even digits 97878
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2c133399d1022d3d6b652cfcf4f25106) (including @Littlefoot answer)

Comment: @AlexeiDelezhov no worries - I think you have accepted the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it with a regular expression you can use

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(TEXTVAL, '(.*\/\/.*)\/\/', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a7390289b26da619b6d22ca120aa635c)